# Want to give the user the option to start the program again

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to give the user the opportunity to enter another calculation. The problem is that I also have a do-while loop before this (this loop is in charge of making sure the users only enters the option 1,2, or 3. So for example. I run my program and I decide to calculate voltage (option 1) but I accidentally enter 4, the program runs all the way to the end to ask me if I want to run the program again, instead of giving me the option to choose 1, 2, 3 which is the way I had the program working before I decided to add this option to the program (to run the program again)

```
/*Pseoudocode
 *THIS PROGRAM WILL CALCULATE VOLTAGE, RESISTANCE, AMPERAGE
 * ASK USER TO CALCULATE WHAT TO CALCULATE
 * IF VOLTS
 *  GET AMPS
 *  GET RESISTANCE
 *  RETURN AMPS * RESISTANCE
 * IF RESISTANCE
 *  GET VOLTS
 *  GET AMPERAGE
 *  RETURN VOLTS / AMPERAGE
 * IF AMPERAGE
 *  GET VOLTS
 *  GET AMPS
 *  RETURN VOLTS / RESISTANCE
 */
package gui;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import bp.Circuit;

/**
 * This program calculates the voltage, resistance, or amperage depending on the
 * input of the user according to the Ohms law.
 *
 * @author
 */
public final class Console {
    /**
     * Class is Final and Contructor is private.
     */
    private Console() {
        // Not called
    }

    /**
     * Makes a Constant for Voltage.
     */
    public static final int USER_CHOICE_VOLTAGE = 1;
    /**
     * Makes a Constant for Amperage.
     */
    public static final int USER_CHOICE_RESISTANCE = 2;
    /**
     * Makes a Constant for Resistance.
     */
    public static final int USER_CHOICE_AMPERAGE = 3;
    public static final int RE_RUN = 10;
    public static final int STOP = 11;

    /**
     * Makes the Body of the Program.
     *
     * @param args
     *            Accepts String arguments.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Creates a Circuit Object
        Circuit myCircuit = new Circuit();
        // Creates a Scanner Object to get input from user
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Holds input from user
        int userChoice;
        // Format the answer to 2 decimals
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");

        int continueRunning = RE_RUN;
        while (continueRunning != STOP) {
            // Statement shows intructions to user
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("This system will calculate the ");
            System.out.println("\tVoltage, Amperage, or Resistance ");
            System.out.println("\tgiven the other two values using Ohms Law.");
            System.out.println("\n");

            // Ask user what to calculate, if it is not one
            // of the options, ask again(while-do loop)
            do {
                System.out.println("Which value would you like to calculate?");
                System.out.println("\t1. Voltage");
                System.out.println("\t2. Resistance");
                System.out.println("\t3. Amperage");
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Please select 1, 2, or 3");
                userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

                // Switch follows cases for what the user would
                // like to calculate
                switch (userChoice) {
                case USER_CHOICE_VOLTAGE:
                    break;

                case USER_CHOICE_RESISTANCE:
                    break;

                case USER_CHOICE_AMPERAGE:
                    break;


                default:  // Do Nothing Since do while loop takes care of this option
                }
            } while (userChoice != USER_CHOICE_VOLTAGE
                    && userChoice != USER_CHOICE_AMPERAGE
                    && userChoice != USER_CHOICE_RESISTANCE
                    && userChoice < 0);
            //Enter a Space
            System.out.println();
            //Ask User if he has another calculation
            System.out.println("Would you like to run this program"
                    + " again? Type:");
            System.out.println("\t(10) for Yes");
            System.out.println("\t(11) to Finish the program");
            //Gets user answer
            continueRunning = keyboard.nextInt();

        }
        System.exit(0);
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create Option 4 for `Exit` and stay in a main loop until user selects it.  You will have a single user input point, no additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Encase the whole thing in a do while loop, prompting the user at the end if they want to keep going and making the while condition true if they say yes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies in your while condition.

```
while (userChoice != USER_CHOICE_VOLTAGE
                && userChoice != USER_CHOICE_AMPERAGE
                && userChoice != USER_CHOICE_RESISTANCE
                && userChoice < 0);
```

With this logic, the do-while loop will end if the user chooses the options, which is what you want. But because of the `userChoice < 0` condition, it *loops if you enter in a negative number.* Try running your program and entering in a negative number at the first prompt. It should do the opposite of what you want.

Sometimes a do-while loop can get confusing because you want it to exit if a certain condition is true, but if the while condition evaluates true, the program loops rather than exits. I've done this before. Try changing your logic so that it only loops if the user inputs a number higher than the valid options. The logic will be simpler and you wouldn't have to use any && unless you want an input of 0 to loop too.